# How to make duplicates with different names from a single file?

Tags: command-line, shell-script, files, file-copy

I want to duplicate the contents of a file. Suppose there is a file named "Hydrogen.element". I want to duplicate the contents of this file with a different name ie.make another file named "Helium.element".
I am actually making a periodic table and I want to use the file named "Hydrogen.element" as a template.

Comment: Question seems incomplete, just copying the files with different filename ?

Comment: yes correct @warl0ck

Answer (score 5):

You would like to copy out a list of files from same source:

```
#!/bin/bash
Elements=('Helium' 'Aluminium' 'Argon') # Items to copy
Source='Hydrogen'  # Copy from this file

for x in "${Elements[@]}"; do 
  cp "$Source" "$x.element"
done
```

After which I will get:

`Aluminium.element  Argon.element  Helium.element`

They all share the same content of `Hydrogen`

Comment: I am probably doing it wrong but when I run your script, I get only `Helium,` file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @jokerdino sorry, I made a mistake, now it works ;-P

Comment: @jokerdino I updated the script and generated result, maybe I'm wrong with your requirements

Comment: Never mind me. It actually is working.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `cp` command?

```
for ELEMENT in {1..10}.element; do cp Hydrogen.element element$ELEMENT; done
```

This command would create 10 files of the name element1.element, element2.element, etc. You can then just rename the files with the relevant element name. If you need to generate more element files, you can change the `{1..10}` to `{1..92}` to create 92 files.

[(reference)](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-do-i-make-multiple-copies-of-a-file-in-the-command-line-665322/#post3259703)

Comment: i tried it ... its not working!

Comment: It should. What happened when you tried?

Comment: Have you used `cd` to navigate to the directory?

Comment: i tried it with multiple file like cp Hydrogen.element Helium.element Aluminium.element Argon.element Arsenic.element Antimony.element Astatine.element Acitnium.element Americium.element

Comment: @PranitBauva The given command would work for only element. I'll update my answer in a while with your updated requirement.